# R Web scraping from different URLs

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

I am web scraping a page at

```
http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog#_r=&collection=&country=&dtype=&from=1890&page=1&ps=100&sid=&sk=&sort_by=nation&sort_order=&to=2017&topic=&view=s&vk=
```

From this url, I have built up a dataframe through the following code:

```
dflist <- map(.x = 1:417, .f = function(x) {
 Sys.sleep(5)
 url <- ("http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog#_r=&collection=&country=&dtype=&from=1890&page=1&ps=100&sid=&sk=&sort_by=nation&sort_order=&to=2017&topic=&view=s&vk=")
read_html(url) %>%
html_nodes(".title a") %>%
html_text() %>%
as.data.frame()
}) %>% do.call(rbind, .)
```

I have repeated the same code in order to get all the data I was interested in and it seems to work perfectly, although is of course a little slow due to the Sys.sleep() thing.

My issue has raised once I have tried to scrape the single projects descriptions that should be included in the dataframe.

For instance, the first project description is at

```
http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog/7118/study-description
```

the second project description is at

```
http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog/6606/study-description
```

and so forth.

My problem is that I can't find a dynamic way to scrape all the projects' pages and insert them in the data frame, being the number in the URLs not progressive nor at the end of the link.

To make things clearer, this is the structure of the website I am  scraping:

```
1.http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog#_r=&collection=&country=&dtype=&from=1890&page=1&ps=100&sid=&sk=&sort_by=nation&sort_order=&to=2017&topic=&view=s&vk=
   1.1.   http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog/7118
        1.1.a http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog/7118/related_materials
        1.1.b http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog/7118/study-description
        1.1.c. http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog/7118/data_dictionary
```

I have scraped successfully level 1. but cannot level 1.1.b. (study-description) , the one I am interested in, since the dynamic element of the URL (in this case: 7118) is not consistent in the website's above 6000 pages of that level.

Comment: It is very unclear as to what your problem is.  It would help us help you if you would clearly include what is your problem when you try to scrape the description.

Comment: My problem is that I can't find a dynamic way to scrape all the projects' pages and insert them in the dataframe, being the number in the URLs not progressive nor at the end of the link.

Comment: You can get the individual urls with `html_attr("href")` in place of `html_text` then use `purrr` to iterate scraping over that list.

Comment: Thanks, this could be an idea, but which command `purrr` command you refer to?

Comment: You can just use `map` or the `apply` family of functions and create a helper function to iterate over the urls

Comment: I have tried, but it does not seem to work on the website's level I am trying to work on (see the post, for explanation).

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the deeper urls from the `.title a` and then scrape those as well.  Here's a small example on how to do that using `rvest` and the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

scraper <- function(x) {

  Sys.sleep(5)
  url <- sprintf("http://catalog.ihsn.org/index.php/catalog#_r=&collection=&country=&dtype=&from=1890&page=%s&ps=100&sid=&sk=&sort_by=nation&sort_order=&to=2017&topic=&view=s&vk=", x)

  html <- read_html(url)

  tibble(title = html_nodes(html, ".title a") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE),
         project_url = html_nodes(html, ".title a") %>% html_attr("href")) 
}

result <- map_df(1:2, scraper) %>% 
  mutate(study_description = map(project_url, ~read_html(sprintf("%s/study-description", .x)) %>% html_node(".xsl-block") %>% html_text()))
```

This isn't complete as to all the things you want to do, but should show you an approach.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful.
I didn't realize about the `~read_html` command.

Comment: `~read_html` isn't a command, it's a formula representation for a function to iterate over a list or vector.  You should search and read more about the `purrr` package, which does the iteration in this example.